# in java, how to make default methods of a interface can not be overridded?

Tags: java, oop

```java
public interface NoExceptionHttpHandler extends HttpHandler {

    @Override
    final default void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        NoExceptionHanlde(exchange);
    }

    void NoExceptionHandle(HttpExchange exchange);
}
```

Just like the code above, I hope that the `HttpHandler` used in my program handles IOException inside the handler method, so the `NoExceptionHttpHandler` interface is defined. In order to prevent anyone from breaking the rule, I hope that the `void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException` method can not be overrided, but `default` cannot be combined with `final`, what should I do to achieve my aim without using abstract classes?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't. If you need a final method, you have to use an abstract class.

Comment: Why can't you use an abstract class?

Comment: @hev1 Because Java does not allow multiple inheritance, I worry that there will be problems later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed. It is added in java for interface evolution . Adding new functionalities for existing interface.

You dont even have to use default method on a new interface, its purpose is for modifying existing interface.
Your requirement may also be implemented using static method on interface

If you need to prevent overriding, you have to use abstract classes